# Errors when using Swift in Ubuntu

Tags: swift, xcode, ubuntu

I recently installed Swift for Ubuntu 16.04. Any time I write a statement I receive the following error:

```
1> let i = 10

i: Int = <extracting data from value failed>

error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error
```

I believe I have downloaded all of the necessary dependencies. 
The command swift -version returns the following:

```
Swift version 4.0.3 (swift-4.0.3-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Any way to resolve this issue?